# Building a parameterized EntityFramework Core Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

Hi, I'm trying to build an Expression to get a generic entity by its primary key and getting a parameterized sql query.

Currently I can get the correct WHERE query, but it isn't parameterized.

```
public async Task<TDbo> Get(TKey key, Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    var propertyRef = keySelector.Body;
    var parameter = keySelector.Parameters[0];
    var constantRef = Expression.Constant(key);
    var equals = Expression.Equal(propertyRef, constantRef);
    var comparer = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equals, parameter);

    return await _context.Set<TDbo>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(comparer);
}
```

This results in the following query:
    `SELECT e.\"Id\", e.\"Name\" \r\n FROM \"People\" AS e\r\nWHERE e.\"Id\" = 1\r\nLIMIT 2`,
instead of the wanted:
    `SELECT e.\"Id\", e.\"Name\" \r\n FROM \"People\" AS e\r\nWHERE e.\"Id\" = @__s_0\r\nLIMIT 2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of `Expression.Constant(key)`. Value constant expressions are not parameterized by the query translator. What you need is an expression referring to a property or field of another expression (which *could* be constant). That's basically what C# compiler emits for closures.

One way is to actually use the C# compiler to create lambda expression with closure and take the body:

```
Expression<Func<TKey>> keyValue = () => key;
var variableRef = key.Body;
```

(the `variableRef` is a replacement of yours `constantRef`)

Another way is to use anonymous, tuple or specific class type to create explicit closure instance and bind the corresponding property or field. For instance, with anonymous type:

```
var variableRef = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(new { key }), "key");
```

or with `System.Tuple`:

```
var variableRef = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(Tuple.Create(key)), "Item1");
```

The actual method doesn't really matter (I personally prefer the first variant with lambda) - all they will cause creating parameter by EF Core query translator.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having `TKey`? I do have an `IKey` representing `TDbo`'s primary key.

Comment: If you mean something like `FindAsync` method, yes. it's possible.

Comment: FindAsync requires working directly on the DbSet (as I understand), while I need to make some queries (namely, `Include()`'s), which return me an IQueryable

Comment: @mixandmatch I meant similar to `FindAsync` method arguments and how it builds the predicate expression dynamically using the `IKey` properties.